# "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer.ordererOrg.example.com: no such host

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

While creating a simple-network in Fabric, when creating the channels and joins of the peers and orders I get the following error:

> **2022-01-26 16:34:15.416 CET [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001** Endorser and orderer connections initialized
> Error: Error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.ordererOrg.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer.ordererOrg.example.com: no such host"

[create.sh(docker ps -a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaLSr.png)

[join.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW2eu.png)

through the docker inspection controls I noticed that containers are created without the ip address but only the port.

[docker-compose.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1coot.png)

[docker inspect test-network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSF7F.png)

Comment: See the status of containers, they are exited/stopped. So the ports are not showing. Start the network and then check the containers again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.